# While building the gradle for the new project created in android studio,build fails due to conflict with dependancy

Tags: android, android-studio, dependency-management

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ.

Comment: `You should use EXACT same version`

Answer (score 0):

You can force override version of annotations like this:

Add to your root gradle file:

```
allprojects {
   configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work
Just change the test in build.gradle

From

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

To

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```